# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error in Sinatra App

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin, sinatra-assetpack

I am getting an `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and `SystemStackError stack level too deep` whenever I run my Sinatra app and try to load the index page. It immediately shuts down the app server (Thin). I can't figure out where I'm going wrong and haven't been able to find any similar errors. It seems to be a problem with Sinatra Assetpack. When I comment out the lines in the layout.haml file, I don't get this error. Here is my main app file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'alphadecimal'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'
require 'less'
require 'haml'
#App files
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'settings.rb') #Database

class UberUrlShortener < Sinatra::Base
  set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
  #Less.paths << "#{UberUrlShortener.root}/app/css"

  register Sinatra::AssetPack

  enable :inline_templates

  assets do
    serve '/js',     from: 'app/js'        # Default
    serve '/css',    from: 'app/css'       # Default
    serve '/images', from: 'app/images'    # Default
    # Add all the paths that Less should look in for @import'ed files

    css :app, '/css/app.css', [
      # '/css/bootstrap.css', # bootstrap.less
      '/css/*.css',
      '/css/*.min.css'
    ]

    js :app, '/js/app.js', [
     '/js/*.js'
    ] 

    css_compression :simple
    js_compression :jsmin
  end

  #Routes Controller

  get '/' do
    haml :index
  end

  post '/' do
    @short_url = ShortenedUrl.find_or_create_by_url(params[:url])
    if @short_url.valid?
      haml :success
    else 
      haml :index
    end
  end

  get '/:shortened' do
    short_url = ShortenedUrl.find_by_shortened(params[:shortened])
    redirect short_url.url
  end


  run! if app_file == $0
end

#Model. Later could be seperate file

class ShortenedUrl < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :url
  validates_presence_of :url
  validates_format_of :url, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http))

  def shorten
    self.id.alphadecimal
  end

  def self.find_by_shortened(shortened)
    find(shortened.alphadecimal)
  end
end
```

Here is my index.haml file:

```
%form(action="/" method="POST")
  %label(for="url")
  %input(type="text" name="url" id="url")
  %input(type="submit" value="Shorten")
  -if @short_url.present? && !@short_url.valid?
    %p Invalid URL: #{@short_url.url}
```

Here is my layout.haml file:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:charset => 'utf-8'}
    %title Uber URL Shortener
    %meta{:name => 'description', :content => 'URL Shortner for Uber Digital Agency'}
    %meta{:name => 'author', :content => 'Cody Littlewood'}
    :plain
      <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->

    /Le styles
    !=css :app
    !=js :app

  %body= yield
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "sinatra", "~> 1.4.3", :require => 'sinatra/base'
gem 'thin', '~> 1.5.1' #decide on
gem 'pg', '~> 0.16.0'
gem 'alphadecimal', '1.1.2'
gem 'sinatra-assetpack', '~> 0.2.8'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'less', '~> 2.3.2'
gem 'json', '~> 1.8.0'
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.11.4'
```

Here is the error when ran with debug:

```
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
./views/index.haml:-5: warning: instance variable @haml_buffer not initialized
./views/index.haml:5: warning: instance variable @short_url not initialized
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/configurator.rb:13: warning: instance variable @asset_hosts not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/logging.rb:13: warning: instance variable @silent not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/logging.rb:13: warning: instance variable @trace not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/logging.rb:13: warning: instance variable @silent not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/logging.rb:13: warning: instance variable @trace not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/logging.rb:13: warning: instance variable @silent not initialized
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/logging.rb:13: warning: instance variable @trace not initialized
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/engines/simple.rb:4: warning: ambiguous first argument; put parentheses or even spaces
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/engines/sqwish.rb:11: warning: assigned but unused variable - e
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
/home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-assetpack-0.2.8/lib/sinatra/assetpack/engines/uglify.rb:6: warning: assigned but unused variable - e
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001ba4e28>
Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1879 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification:0x00000001c39398>
Exception `SystemStackError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:150 - stack level too deep
Exception `SystemStackError' at /home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1087 - stack level too deep
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by removing the second parameter in asset block in my main app file which tells Sinatra Assetpack where css and js files should be served. It was creating a conflict within the gem. Code now looks like this and runs without errors:

```
css :app, [
  # '/css/bootstrap.css', # bootstrap.less
  '/css/*.css',
  '/css/*.min.css'
]

js :app, [
 '/js/*.js'
]
```